Jenkins Traub Algorithm Proof
In the paper "A three-stage variable-shift iteration for polynomial zeros and its relation to generalized Rayleigh iteration" 1, Jenkins and Traub prove the convergence of the algorithm analytically, in chapter 3. Later, in chapter 5 they prove that the algorithm is equivalent to the inverse power iteration, with different shifts depending on the corresponding stage in the JT algorithm.
My question now is, why do they go the long way to prove it analytically first when they can go the short path of proving the equivalence to the power iteration method? Is it simply to prove a different rate of convergence?

The purpose is to compare their method and the usual method.
JT said why their method is preferred in the end of section 5.

